Error in a PHP PDO connection with Firebird 2.5
I'm trying to connect and get some data from a Firebird 2.5 database. I use PHP 8.0.30 with XAMPP.
$query = "SELECT FIRST 2 PG.PRODUTOGRADE_IDENTIFICADOR AS ID, P.PRODUTO_DESCRICAO AS PRODUTO, CAST(SUM(VP.VENDAPRODUTO_QUANTIDADE) AS DECIMAL(18, 2)) AS QTD, CAST(SUM(VP.VENDAPRODUTO_VALOR) AS DECIMAL(18, 2)) AS V_TOTAL_VENDA FROM VENDA V INNER JOIN VENDAPRODUTO VP ON VP.VENDA_IDENTIFICADOR = V.VENDA_IDENTIFICADOR INNER JOIN PRODUTOGRADE PG ON VP.PRODUTOGRADE_IDENTIFICADOR = PG.PRODUTOGRADE_IDENTIFICADOR INNER JOIN PRODUTO P ON P.PRODUTO_IDENTIFICADOR = PG.PRODUTO_IDENTIFICADOR WHERE V.VENDA_DATA BETWEEN '2024-01-01' AND '2024-10-22' GROUP BY  PG.PRODUTOGRADE_IDENTIFICADOR, P.PRODUTO_DESCRICAO ORDER BY QTD DESC";

$pdo = new PDO('firebird:dbname=localhost:C:\xampp\htdocs\fbtomysql\banco\TESTE.FDB', 'SYSDBA', 'masterkey');

$select = $pdo->prepare($query);
$select->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$select->execute();
$result = $select->fetchAll();

foreach($result as $x){
    print_r($x);
}

The error:

Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: -817 Dynamic SQL Error SQL error code = -817 Metadata update statement is not allowed by the current database SQL dialect 1 in C:\xampp\htdocs\fbtomysql\index.php:31 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\fbtomysql\index.php(31): PDO->prepare('SELECT FIRST 2 ...') #1 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\fbtomysql\index.php on line 31

I don't understand what is my error.

you are using dialect 1 that not handle decimal with fixed precision, you should try to update the dialect of your database using ALTER DATABASE SET SQL DIALECT 3;

Mr. @StefanoMartini I try to implement ALTER DATABASE SET SQL DIALECT 3; but was not possible. The error was Message: isc_dsql_prepare failed SQL Message : -104 Invalid token Engine Code    : 335544569 Engine Message :
Dynamic SQL Error SQL error code = -104

@StefanoMartini There is no SET SQL DIALECT clause in ALTER DATABASE. Also, dialect 1 does understand decimal with fixed precision (though if the precision is greater than 9, it is actually backed by a DOUBLE PRECISION).

How did you create the database in question? Also, can you reduce the statement to the minimum required to trigger the error?

The weird thing is the "Metadata update statement is not allowed by the current database SQL dialect 1", but you're not executing DDL.

Looking at this question it seems this error can happen when trying to uses time-less dates in dialect 1, which might happen because of your use of BETWEEN '2024-01-01' AND '2024-10-22' (though I haven't verified that yet). In any case, the best solution would be to use a dialect 3 database, or upgrade your database to dialect 3, as dialect 1 has been deprecated for nearly 25 years.

I misread my own answer there; the problem is using connection dialect 3 with a dialect 1 database. Formally, this is a duplicate, but I've added an answer with a PDO Firebird specific solution.

The problem is that you have a dialect 1 database, but you're using connection dialect 3 to connect (that is the default of the PDO Firebird driver). When you reference date/timestamp columns or expressions in such a dialect mismatch, Firebird can produce this error, as in dialect 1, a DATE is a date+time value, while in dialect 3, a DATE is date only, and date+time is TIMESTAMP.
To fix this, you need to add ;dialect=1 to your PDO connection string. See also PDO_FIREBIRD DSN. In other words, use:
'firebird:dbname=localhost:C:\xampp\htdocs\fbtomysql\banco\TESTE.FDB;dialect=1'

instead of
'firebird:dbname=localhost:C:\xampp\htdocs\fbtomysql\banco\TESTE.FDB'

That said, dialect 1 has been deprecated for 25 years and shouldn't be used any more. If possible, you should migrate to dialect 3. However, judging by the name 'fbtomysql', I guess you migrating some old dialect 1 project to MySQL, so that is probably not important for you.
